# Amazon Web Services: -bash: activate: No such file or directory

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, tensorflow

I'm trying to use `Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu)` on Amazon Web Services (AWS). When you login, you get a message as follows (I'm showing part of it here):

```
Please use one of the following commands to start the required environment with the framework of your choice:
for MXNet(+Keras1) with Python3 (CUDA 9) _____________________ source activate mxnet_p36
for MXNet(+Keras1) with Python2 (CUDA 9) _____________________ source activate mxnet_p27
for TensorFlow(+Keras2) with Python3 (CUDA 8) ________________ source activate tensorflow_p36
```

So, what I understood if I would like to run the last environment shown above for instance, is to run the following command:

```
source activate tensorflow_p36
```

When I run the command however, I get the following:

```
-bash: activate: No such file or directory
```

This is also happening for other environment. Why is that? What should I do to solve the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to be in a directory with a script named `activate` for that to work, or to have such a script in your PATH. Whoever built your AMI would know where about where they put that script.

Comment: Yes, you are right. "activate" can be located in something like this path: cd /home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/bin

Comment: ...so, if you run `PATH=/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` first...

Answer (score 0):

A little late over here, but is anaconda installed in the instance. If so please try

```
conda activate tensorflow_p36
```